# Android NDK APP_STL gnustl_shared is no longer supported

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am buiding an android NDK project with Android Studio 3.3 Canady 11, when build project, I got this error:

> Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process 
>   /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with argument
>   {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-23
>   NDK_OUT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-21 -j10 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false
>   LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/build/core/add-application.mk:178:
>   *** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_shared is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See
>   https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more
>   information.    .  Stop.

My machine is Ubuntu 18 and it has android SDK, NDK full.
Plsease help me fix this issue.
Thank all!

**Update**
If I replaced gnustl_shared with either c++_static or c++_shared, it shows more error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib APP_PLATFORM=android-21 -j10 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1
rm -f /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/*
rm -f /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
rm -f /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
mkdir -p /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a
echo [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbserver      ": "[arm-linux-androideabi] /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver"
install -p /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
echo [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbsetup       ": "/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup"
echo "set solib-search-path /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sysroot /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/android/support /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++ /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1/src/ /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/include /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1/android/include /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include" >> /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
mkdir -p /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/main
echo [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ arm  ": "main <= AndroidJni.cpp"
/home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -MMD -MP -MF /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/main/AndroidJni.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -gcc-toolchain /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -fpic -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16  -marm -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-limit-debug-info  -I/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1/src/ -I/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/include -I/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1/android/include -I/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/protobuf-3.6.1/src -I/home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -I/home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -I/home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp -std=c++11    -DANDROID -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1 -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11  --sysroot /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sysroot -isystem /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -c  /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/src/main/cpp/AndroidJni.cpp -o /home/ndqa/Documents/PROJ/code/MyProj/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/main/AndroidJni.o
```

Comment: `APP_STL gnustl_shared is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information. . Stop.` Error says what to do

Comment: dear  Vygintas B, I replaced  gnustl_shared in Application.mk with c++_static or c++_shared but it so more error

Comment: _"but it so more error"_ If you expect anyone to be able to help with a problem you need to specify what the problem is. For example, including the full, exact error message(s) in your question.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a complete log. I don't see any errors in that block of text.

Comment: its is Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/ndqa/opt/Android-SDK/ndk-bundle/.....

Comment: Yes, but there are no errors in the log that you posted. There's "an error happened", but the error itself is not included.

Answer (score 38):

1. switch `APP_STL := gnustl_static` to either `c++_static` or `c++_shared` in file `Application.mk`

> APP_STL := c++_static

2. The Android OS switched to clang several years ago. Future versions of the NDK will remove GCC, so the sooner you start testing your project with clang the better!

> 1. For ndk-build, remove lines setting NDK_TOOLCHAIN or NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION.
> 2. For cmake, remove lines setting ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN.
> 3. For standalone toolchains, use the clang/clang++ binaries instead of gcc/g++.
> 4. For other build systems, ask the owners of that build system.

---

see more details:

> https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support
>
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md#how-to-fix-common-problems

Comment: i have to replace all the line in other file, f ***